# Serilize List<List<string>> in ProtoBuf-net and Deserialize as a C++ vector<vector<string>>

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a list of list objects in C#

```
List<List<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();
```

**NOTE: number elements in the lists changes at runtime**
which I want to Serialize using protobuf

And later I need to Deserialize data using `protocolBuffer` in C++ as a `vector<vector<string>>`

Can this be done? Wondering how to define .proto file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that in .proto you'd need to add a layer:

```
message Outer {
    repeated Inner items = 1;
}
message Inner {
    repeated string items = 1;
}
```

Because of this structural aspect of the underlying protobuf spec, protobuf-net does not currently support directly-nested/jagged lists/arrays - but it is on my roadmap to support this by spoofing the above layout in protobuf-net's imagination.